# $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to evaluate the following limit
$$ \lim_{x \to  0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}$$
I tried  with Hopital but I can't understand where I'm making mistakes.
The final result is 0.
Can someone help me?

- ok I see that hte function in not well defined for $x \rightarrow 0^+$, and supposing that the right function is

$$(x|\ln x|)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to  0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}=\\
 \lim_{x \to  0^+}e^{\log((x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x})} =
\lim_{x \to  0^+}e^{\frac{\log((x |\ln x|))}{x}}= 
+\infty 
$$

Comment: Can you please show your work? It would help others help you.

Comment: How is $(x\ln x)^{1/x}$ defined for $0\lt x\lt1$? You're taking, in general, a non-integer power of a *negative* number in that range.

Comment: Graphing this thing on desmos shows that this limit shouldn't even exist at all

Comment: If you meant the limit as $x$ goes to $1$ from the right, then the result will be $0$

Comment: also for wolfram alpha the limit doesn't exist

Comment: Imo it is not merely that the limit doesn't exist but in fact the function isn't well defined in any right boundary of zero...So we doesn't even have a function to talk about its limit!

Comment: @DonAntonio It would be well defined for $\frac1{x_n}=2n+1$ assuming that for $a>0$ $\sqrt[2n+1]{-a^3}=-a$.

Comment: make it clear please , does this thing have absolute value bars or not

Comment: for  $0<x<1$, $\log(x)<0$ and so $(x\log x)^{1/x}$ does not exist.

Comment: @user That doesn't really help as the function *must be defined* over a continuum of points to the right of $\;x=0\;$ ...and it isn't. That it is defined on certain points (even infinitely many) makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this
$$
\lim_{x \to  0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}
$$
Take the logarithm of the expression $(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}$ and call it $L$
$$
L = \frac{1}{x}\ln(x |\ln x|)
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}(x |\ln x|) = 0
$$
that means
$$
L = \frac{\ln(0^+)}{0^+} = -\infty
$$
That means that the expression of which the logarithm is $L$ is
$$
\lim_{x \to  0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x} = 0
$$

Comment: As noticed we have a problem with $x\log x<0$.

Comment: so it means that the limit is not well stated, so should we consider it with absolute value bars

Answer (score 1):

For  $0<x<1/e$, $1< \log\big(\frac1x\big)$ and so
$$
\begin{align}
(x|\log x|)^{1/x}&=\exp\Big(\frac{1}{x}\big(\log x+ \log(|\log x|)\big)\Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(\frac{\log x +\log\big(\log\tfrac1x\big)}{x}\Big)\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\Big(1+ \frac{\log(\log\tfrac1x)}{\log x} \Big)\right)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0+}0
\end{align}
$$

since $\frac{\log x}{x}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0+}-\infty$, and
$\frac{\log\big(\log\tfrac1x\big)}{\log x}\stackrel{u=\log(1/x)}{=}-\frac{\log u}{u}\xrightarrow{u\rightarrow\infty}0$

Answer (score 0):

As noticed in the comments, since $\log x<0$ the expression for the given limit is not well defined and we should consider

$$\lim_{x \to  0^+}(x |\ln x|)^\frac{1}{x}$$

With reference to this expression, firstly we need to show that

$$x |\ln x| \to 0$$

then note that $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: in this case, applying $e^{log } $ to the function the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: @Anne Could you check the exact formulation for the problem. Asnoticed in this form the expression is not well defined. For the modified expression, we need to prove that $x|\log x| to 0$.

Comment: unfortunately the formulas is well reported but it was written badly in the book evidently. So I'm trying the understand what is the limit with the absolute value

Comment: @Anne We only need to prove that $x |\ln x| \to 0$ since (simbolically) $0^\infty=0$. I can't read your progress at the moment.

Comment: sorry, I'm extemely low to write, I edited the original question but Im afraid it is not readable

Comment: anyway by hopital it is possible to prove that $x*|ln x|$ tends to $0$

Comment: @Anne Well done and since $(x|\log x|)^\frac1x <(x|\log x|\to 0$ we can conclude.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anne By your way we have $$e^{\frac{\log (x|\log x|)}{x}} \to e^{-\infty}=0$$ since $$\frac{\log (x|\log x|)}{x} \to -\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

In this problem letting $x\to 0^+$ along a certain sequence can lead to good insight. For example, you could let $x_n= 1/e^n.$ Then

$$(x_n|\ln x_n|)^{1/x_n} = (n/e^n)^{e^n}.$$

So think about this: That $n/e^n\to 0$ is well known at this level. Thus for $n$ large, $n/e^n<1/2.$ And what is $(1/2)^{e^n}?$ It's $1/2$ raised to a huge power. That suggests $0$ is the limit.